# Getting next date and previous day date

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I basically want to convert a particular date (x) to the previous day date(x - 1 day) and also to the next day date (x + 1 day). I am using the following code for this :

```
NSDate *datePlusOneDay = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60 * 60 * 24)];
```

However I have my date (x) in NSString format, and I need to convert the NSString(`myDateString`) to NSDate(`myDate`) before applying the above code.
I have a NSString containing date in format MM-dd-yyyy.
For converting I am using the following code , but I am getting absurd values.

```
 NSLog(@"myDateString=%@",myDateString);//output:myDateString=10-25-2012//all correct
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate=[formatter dateFromString:myDateString];
NSLog(@"myDate=%@",myDate);//output:myDate=2012-10-24 18:30:00 +0000 // I only want the date to be shown // and why has the format changed
NSDate *datePlusOneDay = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60 * 60 * 24)];
NSLog(@"datePlusOneDay=%@",datePlusOneDay);//output:datePlusOneDay=2012-10-25 18:30:00 +0000// I only want the date to come , not time // and why has the format changed
```

Later again I need to convert the NSDate to NSString

```
NSString *curentString=[formatter stringFromDate:datePlusOneDay];
NSLog(@"curentString=%@",curentString); //output:curentString=10-26-2012
```

Similarly I also want to get the previous date.
Please help guys !! and ho ho MERRY CHRISTMAS !!

Comment: Whenever you log, print, use nsdate object the timestamp will come, you can run from it.

Comment: [nsdate date] will give you current date, convert it into string or dateComponents and +1 / -1 and update the string... thats it.

Comment: I do not want the previous date and next date of the current date. I want the next date and the previous date of a dynamic date !!

Comment: @Maverik Isn't `[NSDate date]` dynamic enough?

Comment: @H2CO3 [NSDate date] will give the current date. I have nothing to do with the current date. I want the next date and the previous date of a dynamic date (fetched from server). !!

Comment: @Maverik : but 60*60*24 will not give you always correct, leap year, 30,31 etc...and the worst is 1582's October check once...

Comment: @Maverik Then why don't you grab the sate from the server as, for example, plaintext, and use `NSDateFormatter` to obtain the date object from it?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : so what to use instead of 60*60*24 !!

Comment: I have posted the answer...have a look

Comment: @H2CO3 : Sir, kindly check my answer and tell is it ok?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Perfect, +1 - I'll improve the style a bit.

Comment: @H2CO3: sure sir plzz, I am here to learn...

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Here you are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do as: `componets.day = 1` to obtain the next, `-1` for the previous day.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; // your date from the server will go here.
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.day = 1;
NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];

NSLog(@"newDate -> %@",newDate);
```

Comment: Also, @OP: don't forget to release everything you `+alloc`-ed.

Comment: ok, i prefer new as it is shortcut, is there much differnce in alloc+init

Comment: @AnooVaidya there's no difference, really :) I just prefer `alloc-init` because it's used more often, and anyway it makes the mechanism of creating an instance explicitly visible.

Comment: Someone downvoted, lol.... they start playing in SO full with ego or what...that is ridiculous.

Answer (score 4):

The below code should get you the previous date:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:-1]; // replace "-1" with "1" to get the datePlusOneDay
NSDate *dateMinusOneDay = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:myDate options:0];
```

Merry Xmas :)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];

[components setHour:-[components hour]];
[components setMinute:-[components minute]];
[components setSecond:-[components second]];
NSDate *today = [cal dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[[NSDate alloc] init] options:0]; //This variable should now be pointing at a date object that is the start of today (midnight);

[components setHour:-24];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];
NSDate *yesterday = [cal dateByAddingComponents:components toDate: today options:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple solution for previous date:-

```
NSDate *datePlusOneDay = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(60 * 60 * 24)];
NSLog(@"datePlusOneDay=%@",datePlusOneDay);
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 Solution

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -2, to: Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

function for previousDay

```
-(void)previousDay
{
  NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];


    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    comps.day =-1;
    NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    EndingDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:sevenDays];

}
```

function for next day

```
-(void)nextDay
{
  NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];


    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    comps.day =1;
    NSDate *sevenDays = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    EndingDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:sevenDays];

}
```